# In binarysearch, if the element isn't found, why is the convention to subtract one from where it should do?

Tags: java, c, algorithm, language-agnostic, binary-search

I know this is getting down to the nitty gritty, but when doing a binary search and the element is not found, what is the rational of return `(-(insertion point) -1)`. In particular the `-1` part. This is how Java does it and I don't see why they made the convention `-1` instead of just `-(insertion point)`. Obviously the negative is to indicate the value wasn't actually found in the array/list. I'm guessing it comes from C where it was easier to do some bitwise operation that negated and subtracted one.

Note: I've seen code written in C, C++ and Java that use this convention and I'm wondering where the convention came from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because the insertion point might be zero, and you don't have -0 for int (unlike floating point numbers), so you need some other way to indicate it unambiguously.

As it says in the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch(byte[],%20byte)):

> Note that this guarantees that the return value will be >= 0 if and only if the key is found.

Of course, there are other ways to represent the insertion position; this just happens to be quite elegant because it requires no extra information such as the container's size in order to be used to insert the element appropriately.

---

In terms of where the convention arose - the mists of time, I'll bet!

As pure conjecture, I can imagine it coming about in C (or maybe even earlier languages), where it was a much cleaner way to encode the values than the alternatives.

An "obvious" alternative encoding might be to use the sign bit to indicate presence/absence, and the remaining bits to indicate the insertion position:

```
S PPPP....P
^            0 means "present", 1 means "absent"
  ^---....^  These bits denote the position in the container.
```

To extract the position in the case that the sign bit is set, you need to mask the bits. This is easy in Java, where ints are defined as having 32 bits (simply use `value & 0x7FFFFFF`); but to write it in portable C, you'd need to do something like:

```
value = binarySearch(...);
if (value < 0) {
  insertionPosition = value & ~(1 << sizeof(int) * 8 - 1);
  ...
}
```

(Forgive me if that's not quite right - this is why Java programmers shouldn't try to write C...)

Even with a fixed width, it's a bit cryptic:

```
value = binarySearch(...);
if (value < 0) {
  insertionPosition = value & 0x7FFFFFFF;  // What's this magic number?!
  ...
}
```

That's rather ugly, and rather easy to get wrong, if you have to write it in a number of places. Sure, you could write a little method to do this math for you, but method calls are expensive (at least, they might have been back in the day).

Using the `(-(insertion point) -1)` convention, you can write simple, easy-to-read, quick code:

```
value = binarySearch(...);
if (value < 0) {
  insertionPosition = -value - 1;
  ...
}
```

Comment: Why does Java specify `-(insertion point) -1` instead of the simpler, clearer, more obvious `~(insertion point)` like C# does? Is there some edge case in Java where this would be inappropriate?